# Pandas boolean comparisson on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I am getting the error  when I make a comparison on a single element in a dataframe, but I don't understand why.

I have a dataframe df with timeseries data for a number of customers, with some null values within it:

```
df.head()
                    8143511  8145987  8145997  8146001  8146235  8147611  \
2012-07-01 00:00:00      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
2012-07-01 00:30:00    0.089      NaN    0.281    0.126    0.190    0.500   
2012-07-01 01:00:00    0.090      NaN    0.323    0.141    0.135    0.453   
2012-07-01 01:30:00    0.061      NaN    0.278    0.097    0.093    0.424   
2012-07-01 02:00:00    0.052      NaN    0.278    0.158    0.170    0.462
```

In my script, the line 
`if pd.isnull(df[[customer_ID]].loc[ts]):`
generates an error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

However, if I put a breakpoint on the line of script, and when the script stops I type this into the console:

```
pd.isnull(df[[customer_ID]].loc[ts])
```

the output is:

```
8143511    True
Name: 2012-07-01 00:00:00, dtype: bool
```

If I allow the script to continue from that point, the error is generated immediately.

If the boolean expression can be evaluated and has the value `True`, why does it generate an error in the if expression? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: check answer of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o

Comment: ok, thank you. So if I use 
pd.isnull(df_gen[[customer_ID]].loc[ts].item())  then the boolean is evaluated OK, but I don't understand why teh original didn't work.

Comment: Because original returns `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` object it is not boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second set of `[]`  was returning a series which I mistook for a single value. The simplest solution is to remove `[]`:

```
if pd.isnull(df[customer_ID].loc[ts]):
       pass
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies in the `if` statement.

When you code

```
if this:
    print(that)
```

`this` will be evaluated as `bool(this)`.  And that better come back as `True` or `False`.

However, you did:

```
if  pd.isnull(df[[customer_ID]].loc[ts]):
    pass  # idk what you did here because you didn't say... but doesn't matter
```

Also, you stated that `pd.isnull(df[[customer_ID]].loc[ts])` evaluated to:

```
8143511    True
Name: 2012-07-01 00:00:00, dtype: bool
```

Does that look like a `True` or `False`?
What about `bool(pd.isnull(df[[customer_ID]].loc[ts]))`?

> ```
> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
> ```

So the lesson is:  **A `pd.Series` cannot be evaluated as `True` or `False`**

It is, however, a `pd.Series` of `True`s and `False`s.

And that is why it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, the lesson I learnt is `df[[customer_ID]].loc[ts]` returns a `pd.Series` not a single value

Answer (score 2):

Problem is you need compare scalar for return scalar (`True`, `False`), but there is one item `Series`, which is converted to one item `boolean Series`.

Solutions is converting to scalar using [Series.item](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html) or [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) with selecting first value by `[0]`:

```
customer_ID = '8143511'
ts = '2012-07-01 00:00:00'

print (df[[customer_ID]].loc[ts].item())
nan

if pd.isnull(df[[customer_ID]].loc[ts]).item():
    print ('super')
```

```
print (df[[customer_ID]].loc[ts].values[0])
nan

if pd.isnull(df[[customer_ID]].loc[ts]).values[0]:
    print ('super')
```

But if use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), get `scalar` (if not duplicated index or columns names):

```
print (df.loc[ts, customer_ID])
nan

customer_ID = '8143511'
ts = '2012-07-01 00:00:00'
if pd.isnull(df.loc[ts, customer_ID]):
    print ('super')
```

Comment: Thanks. This made me realise the second set of `[]` was causing the problem, so these solutions work but simpler to remove a square bracket.

Comment: Glad can help you. Good luck!