# logic element-wise operations in pandas time-series dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, time-series, logical-operators

I have a pandas DataFrame with a timestamp datetime index and values that correspond to each date. E.g., `df = pd.DataFrame(['0.11', '0.07', '0.04', '-0.11', '-0.04', '0.08', '0.1'], index=['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-06', '2017-01-07'], columns=['values'])`.

I would like to create an additional column (let's call it `'new_value'`) based on the present and historical values of the above dataframe.

The logic should be:

1. if a value is greater than or equal to 0.1, 'new_value' should be set
   to -1,
2. once 'new_value' is set to -1, it should remain -1 until a value
   less than or equal to 0.05 is registered,
3. if a value is less than or equal to -0.1, 'new_value' should be set
   to +1,
4. once 'new_value' is set to +1, it should remain +1 until a value
   greater than or equal to -0.05 is registered,
5. otherwise 'new_value' is equal to 0

I have tried multiple solutions, but can't seem to solve this problem. E.g.,

```
new_frame = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(len(df.index),index=df.index,columns=['new_value'])
for date in df.index:
    if df['value'][date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')] > 0.1:
        new_frame.set_value(date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),'new_value',-1)
```

But I receive the error: `'ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'`

If I then change the third line to:

```
if df['value'][date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').item() > 0.1:
```

I receive the error: `'ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar'`

Answer (score 2):

## [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

```
s = df['values'].astype(float)
al = np.array([-.1, -.05])
bl = np.array([1, np.nan, 0])
ar = np.array([.05, .1])
br = np.array([0, np.nan, -1])
l = bl[al.searchsorted(s.values)]
r = br[ar.searchsorted(s.values, side='right')]

df.assign(new_values=pd.Series(l + r, s.index).ffill())

           values  new_values
2017-01-01   0.11        -1.0
2017-01-02   0.07        -1.0
2017-01-03   0.04         0.0
2017-01-04  -0.11         1.0
2017-01-05  -0.04         0.0
2017-01-06   0.08         0.0
2017-01-07    0.1        -1.0
```

***how it works***

- need to get just a series of floats, name it `s`
- set up left side breakpoints `al`
- set up left side mapped values `bl`
- set up right side breakpoints `ar`
- set up right side mapped values `br`
- `searchsorted` will find the index that values should be placed before
- use the indices from `searchsorted` to identify mapped values
- when looking for the right side values, I use `side='right'`
- map values again.
- add left and right results.  `nan` + value will be `nan`
- `ffill` to propagate values forward.

---

***setup***
*assuming dataframe `df` given by OP*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    ['0.11', '0.07', '0.04', '-0.11',
     '-0.04', '0.08', '0.1'],
    ['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02',
     '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04',
     '2017-01-05', '2017-01-06',
     '2017-01-07'],
    ['values']
)

           values
2017-01-01   0.11
2017-01-02   0.07
2017-01-03   0.04
2017-01-04  -0.11
2017-01-05  -0.04
2017-01-06   0.08
2017-01-07    0.1
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. In terms of building my understanding, is anyone able to explain why my original approach would not work?

Comment: @Panda_User see [***this answer***](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43222675/2336654)  Feel free to up vote it if its helpful :-)

Comment: @Panda_User I see that you got stuck at the initial stages... Yeah, what I gave you is a vectorized solution.  Your were going down the road of using loops.  Now you don't have to.  A number of people fall into the trap of evaluating series as booleans when executing a loop.