# Python: vlookup on complex arrays searching through multiple columns for each row

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, if-statement

I have the following problem where my python code doesn't work. Hoping for some suggestions on why and how to resolve.

Here's the example dataframe:

```
cust_id max_nibt nibt_0 nibt_1  nibt_10 line_0  line_1  line_10
11  200 -5  200 500 100 200 300
22  300 -10 100 300 100 200 300
33  400 -20 0   400 100 200 300
```

```
for i in range (0,11):
    if (df4['nibt_%s' % i] == df4['max_nibt']): 
        df4['model_line'] = df4['line_%s' % i]
```

The code gives me the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

However, when I use `.any()`, it only gives me the last range assigning model_line = line_10. when i use `.all()`, the answer is the same for all the cust_ids. thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I have to guess at what you want, but you clearly are not using `pd.Series` correctly... see [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43222675/2336654) for a better explanation.

*IIUC*:
You want to fill in values from `line_x` when `nibt_x` equals `max_nibt`

```
# filter to get `nibt` columns and find the first column that equals max
nibt_maxes = df.filter(regex='nibt_\d+').eq(df.max_nibt, 0).idxmax(1)

# swap out the string `nibt` with `line`
lines = nibt_maxes.replace('nibt', 'line', regex=True)

# use `lookup` and assign values
df['model'] = df.lookup(lines.index, lines.values)

   cust_id  max_nibt  nibt_0  nibt_1  nibt_10  line_0  line_1  line_10  model
0       11       200      -5     200      500     100     200      300    200
1       22       300     -10     100      300     100     200      300    300
2       33       400     -20       0      400     100     200      300    300
```

Comment: Well done! A vectorized version. Adding `lookup` to my pandas toolkit!

Comment: Thank you @Parfait

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `.loc` for row index conditionals. As is, your `for` loop compares all values of both columns (i.e., pandas Series) for equality and hence any number of boolean outcomes:

```
for i in [0,1,10]:
  df4.loc[df4['nibt_%s' % i] == df4['max_nibt'], 'model_line'] = df4['line_%s' % i]
```

Alternatively, since this `for` loop can overwrite the same new column, *model_line*, consider adding suffix versions of *model_line*:

```
for i in [0,1,10]:
  df4.loc[df4['nibt_%s' % i] == df4['max_nibt'], 'model_line_%s' % i] = df4['line_%s' % i]
```

Comment: Great! Glad to help. When I started off in pandas, this error was probably the most common I encountered. Please do accept the most helpful answer (tick mark to side) to confirm resolution (even helps future readers).

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare Series like that because how will pandas know which elements you want to compare to each other?

If I understand correctly you can do:

```
for i in range(0,11):
  for j,k in df.iterrows():
    if k['nibt_%s' % i] == k['max_nibt']:
      df.iloc[j]['model_line'] = df.iloc[j]['line_%s' % i]
```